Shutdown Confirmation is missing on HyperOS 14
I faced a problem with my new updated system, HyperOS 14. before I updated my system, there was a feature Shutdown Confirmation. When I want to turn off my device, that forces me to insert a password. If correct, then the device will turn off.
I don't know why this feature was not found after the update.

